# Error Could not find a part of the path when build the testing .net core application

Tags: c#, build

I have a testing (unit testing and integration testing) app in .net core 5,,
Another explanation that I can say is that in my solution I have 3 Project , 1 for App and 2 other for testing
when I build my project I get this error

when I build my project I get this error

> Error     Could not find a part of the path 'C:\testProject\obj\Debug\net6.0\testProject.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.  testProject C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets  190

Why I get this error?
How can I solve this error?
Thank a bunch

Comment: I'd start by increasing the MSBuild project build output verbosity (under tools -> options -> projects and solutions -> build and run), building the project again, copying everything from the Output pane into a text editor and searching it for any references to testProject.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig. This should at least give you an idea of whether that file is being created, or created and deleted, or maybe created in a different location to that in the error message.

Comment: The path looks like you have created your solution at the root of C:\ - or MSBuild picks up the output path incorrectly.

Comment: The path also looks suspiciously like it was declared using `$(SolutionDir)` in the `csproj` and then the `csproj` was built individually outside of VS, e. g. with dotnet CLI or plain msbuild. In that case there is no "solution directory" and the `$(SolutionDir)` variable will be empty. If that is indeed the reason you could either change the path declaration to not contain `$(SolutionDir)` or add `/p:SolutionDir=<sln_path>` to the msbuild call to have the variable available.

Answer (score 24):

The issue is that the path is very long. You can fix it by enabling "long path support". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Comment: I also had this error. I moved the project to a different folder (that had a shorter path) and the error disappeared! I didn't try to enable long path support though